# Linking up C++ and Python

Tags: python, c++

I am trying to set up a program in Visual Studio where I link up a C++ file and a Python file. The printing statement from the Python statement still outputs and I am able to change it. However, whenever I run the program my console says:

Start 1

2

00000000

File "C:\Users\marce\source\repos\PythonCPPSample\Release\setup.py", line 4
print("Hello everyone! My name is Marcel.")

IndentationError: expected an indented block after function definition on line 3

3

Is this really a syntax problem? What can I do to fix this? Here is my code:

source.cpp

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
cout << "Start 1 \n";
Py_Initialize();
cout << "2\n";
PyObject* my_module = PyImport_ImportModule("setup");
cerr << my_module << "\n";
PyErr_Print();
cout << "3\n";
PyObject* my_function = PyObject_GetAttrString(my_module,
    "printsomething");
cout << "4\n";
PyObject* my_result = PyObject_CallObject(my_function, NULL);
Py_Finalize();
}
```

setup.py

```
import re
import string
def printsomething():
print("Hello everyone! My name is Marcel.")
```

Comment: "Is this really a syntax problem? What can I do to fix this?" Well, yes? Did you try to use the Python code by itself? Notice how it gives you the same exception message? If you really don't understand why, you should probably try to study Python fundamentals before trying to interoperate with C++. Indentation is crucial in Python, and this is just about the first thing one learns.

Comment: "What can I do to fix this?" Another important skill is to attempt to read and understand error messages. Notice how this one says "expected an indented block after function definition"?

Comment: I have already read the error message and I have already indented the printing statement underneath the printsomething() function, and that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Make sure everything is saved, and if you still have a minimal reproducible example, try the question again. What you describe doesn't make sense, however.

Comment: This has **nothing to do with** the C++ code; and if trivial errors like this in the Python code aren't **immediately** apparent to you, you should be spending more time mastering the fundamentals of Python, before trying to work on embedding it from C++. "I have already read the error message and I have already indented the printing statement underneath the printsomething() function, and that didn't fix the problem." - if that were the case, then you should have been able to show a proper [mre] with the indent fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message is appearing in the console application, but even if the printing statement were to be indented underneath the function in the setup.py it would not fix the problem. This is because the python file that it's linking to had not been pulled up from the correct release folder.

So, I just had to look at the path to the .py file that was shown on the console. Right click on the Source file in Solution Explorer and add existing item. Go to the file referred to by the path, and then click on it. On that file, you can fix the indentation problem and the problem as a whole.

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)